# Magnetic Susceptibility at Arbitrary Temperature

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics

I'm currently working on an assignment where the questions is:

> Consider a gas of N noninteracting electrons in a uniform magnetic field **B** = B$\hat{z}$ in a macroscopic system. Assume that the field affects only spin of the electron and not its orbital motion, and denote the Bohr magneton by $\mu_{B}$. Show that the magnetic susceptibility $\chi$ at arbitrary temperature is given by $$\chi = 2\mu_{B}^2 \int d\epsilon \frac{dD(\epsilon)}{d\epsilon}f(\epsilon)$$
>   where $D(\epsilon)$ is the density of orbital states and $f(\epsilon)$ is the Fermi-Direc distribution function. Express $\chi$ in terms of $N$ and fundamental temperature $\tau$ in the high-temperature limit, assuming that the lowest single-particle energy is zero and $D(0) = 0$.

Now, in a previous assignment, we already had the question:

> Consider a gas of N noninteracting electrons in a uniform magnetic field **B** = B$\hat{z}$ in a macroscopic system. Assume that the field affects only spin of the electron and not its orbital motion. Find the spin magnetic susceptibility, $$\chi = \frac{dM}{dB}$$ where $M$ is the total magnetization of the system. Denote the magnitude of the magnetic moment associated with the electron spin and charge as $\mu_B$ (Bohr magneton).

And the solution to that question was

> $\chi = 2D(\epsilon_F)\mu_B^2$

Clearly quite similar to the desired function for the newer question.

Now, I've been looking at this question for two days. I've gone over the solution to the old question numerous times, but I don't know where to start for the second question - I don't know at what point the arbitrary temperature consideration becomes relevant and how it changes the analysis.

I am by no means looking for a solution to the question, but I am hoping that somebody could give me a pointer or two to get me going in the right direction.

At first glance, I suspect the solution has something to do with the equations $$ N = \int_0^\infty d\epsilon D(\epsilon)f(\epsilon)$$ (as opposed to the equation $$ N = \int_0^{\epsilon_f} d\epsilon D(\epsilon)$$ which was used in the previous assignment), and $$ M = \mu_BN$$

But I don't know how to get from these to the final result.

Magnetic susceptibility is a concept that both my class's notes and my textbook don't go into much detail on. Like I said, any hints or pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magnetic field shifts the energy levels of spin-up/down electrons by $\mp\mu_{B}B$, and there should be corresponding changes in the density of states for spin-up/down electrons.

Furthermore, in this problem, we are interested in the case where the magnetic field is weak, so you can Taylor-expand in powers of $B$ and take the leading non-vanishing term.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean in your second sentence. What function do we Taylor-expand? The density of states function?

Comment: The density of state (DOS) for up or down electrons after considering the energy shift $\mp \mu_{B}B$ caused by the magnetic field depends on $B$. ($D(\epsilon)$ is DOS at $B=0$.) So you can expand this in powers of $B$.

Comment: Ok, but I don't understand the important of this. I know that the energy shift is $\mp\mu_BB$. But how does the taylor expansion, which produces derivatives at a point, get me to an integral? And what do you mean by $D(\epsilon)$ is DOS at $B = 0$? $D(\epsilon)$ IS the DOS, regardless of B. And we don't know what B is so why assume it's zero?

Comment: I don't understand how we would go from having a term of $D(\epsilon)$ to $\int d\epsilon \frac{dD(\epsilon)}{d\epsilon}f(\epsilon)$ in the final answer. Why/how does the arbitrary temperature parameter result in that kind of change?

Comment: My guess is that the problem did not state this point clearly. To get the desired answer, $D(\epsilon)$ has to be the DOS for $B=0$. The energy shift $\mp \mu_{B}B$ due to magnetic field changes it to $D(\epsilon \pm \mu_{B}B)$, where upper and lower signs correspond to spin up and down, and you can Taylor expand this.

Comment: But if I do a taylor expansion, how come I only keep the first order term? Why not the 0th order? What about all the other terms?

Comment: Let's go to the chat room you've created before.